# Invisible Stack Overflow users?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Why isn't the content of field `Display Name` displayed for Stack Overflow user [erikkallen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47161/erikkallen)?

The screenshot below is from Opera, but I see the same in Firefox (or rather I don't).

---

[alt text http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/SO/empty_erikkallen_16c.png](http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/SO/empty_erikkallen_16c.png)

Comment: Actually, the missing field that surprises me is the one between the stackoverflow logo and the gravatar.

Comment: @mmyers: it is empty because I have blocked www.gravatar.com (using the "hosts" file.)

Comment: I meant the one up above the gravatar. But I realized later that that name is also blank for unregistered users (although I'm not sure why it's useful to have the same information twice on the page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to set a display name (i.e. you keep your profile completely empty). The username of your OpenID URL is taken as SO username then.

Comment: But if the display name IS empty, those profile fields should be populated by your openID URL.