# The Users page is not ordered by name in the name tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, users, users-page

Right now, the [first users by name](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=name) are:

- ricree (rep 1,226)
- garg (rep 91)
- deanbates (rep 331)
- spencerholleman (rep 33)

This is not ordered by name. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the specific users names, you'll see that they are empty.

The username will be dependent on what OpenID they used to log in. And apparently, the username is not the same as the name in that case.

Comment: Exactly---that shouldn't be possible though, you're not allowed to change you username to nothing.

Comment: @balpha: True. If I'm not mistaken, I think there's a question here somewhere about that. Aah, here it is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27770/invisible-stack-overflow-users as usual [status-bydesign]

Comment: *That* is what I was missing. It is by design, but I find it confusing at least.

Comment: also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25542/display-names-bugs-no-allowed-cant-reset-unset-kills-profile-copy

Comment: @fretje: Nice find [I can just imagine you typing the first part of the comment, then searching, and then typing "Aah, here it is" :-) ] --- anyhow, the user page search order is definitely a problem caused by this that shouldn't be by-design

Comment: @balpa: [that's actually what I did... thanks to the new comment editing feature ;-) ]

Comment: Status "by-design" means anything that is wrong but either (a) too hard to fix, or (b) no fun to fix. :)